# Get VideoID from path

Tags: android, video, mediastore

I need to get ID of video which is saved in folder named **.videos** so it is hidden. I have tried to query by this method.

```
public static Uri getVideoContentUri(Context context, File videoFile) {
    String filePath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID },
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[] { filePath }, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        cursor.close();
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (videoFile.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But all I got is 0 everytime.
**expected problem:** Folder is hidden that is the reason I can not get the ID?